# Iterate over the reverse of a sorted set in Scala?

Tags: scala, treeset, sortedset

I have a mutable SortedSet and I can iterate over it by doing `for (item <- nameOfMySortedSet)`. However I would like to be able to do the same thing, but over the reverse of `nameOfMySortedSet`. I do not seem to see a `reverse()` option for this datatype? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution,

```
val sSet = SortedSet(4,3,5)
sSet.foldLeft(List[Int]())((x,y)=>y::x)
```

If you have to do this too often, you may have to save `Set` in the reverse order. Use a different `Ordering`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try building a new SortedSet with the ordering reversed:

```
scala> val mySet = collection.mutable.SortedSet("1", "2", "3")
mySet: scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet[String] = TreeSet(1, 2, 3)

scala> collection.mutable.SortedSet(mySet.toSeq:_*)(mySet.ordering.reverse)
res0: scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet[String] = TreeSet(3, 2, 1)
```

Or you can just convert it to a list or seq and run the reverse:

```
scala> mySet.toSeq.reverse
res1: Seq[String] = ArrayBuffer(3, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works, but I would not want to defend it as efficient:

```
  val s = collection.SortedSet(1,3,4)
  for (i <- s.to[List].reverse)
    println(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times we need just the last few elements, that's what iterators are for.
There's another way without folding over all the elements or constructing a new SortedSet instance altogether.

We can have a reverse iterator, that goes over from the last picking each element one by one with log(n) complexity every `next` invocation.

The following is an optimised implementation for the same.

```
object SortedSetExtras {

  implicit class ReverseIterator[A](val set: mutable.SortedSet[A]) extends AnyVal {

    def reverseIterator: Iterator[A] = new Iterator[A] {
      var upNext: Option[A] = None
      var upNextComputed: Boolean = false

      private def recompute(): Unit = {
        if (!upNextComputed) {
          upNext = upNext match {
            case Some(value) => set.until(value).lastOption
            case None => set.lastOption
          }
          upNextComputed = true
        }
      }

      override def hasNext: Boolean = if (upNextComputed) upNext.nonEmpty else {
        recompute()
        hasNext
      }

      override def next: A = {
        if (upNextComputed) {
          upNext.foreach(_ => upNextComputed = false)
          upNext.get
        } else {
          recompute()
          next()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Actual usage-

```
import SortedSetExtras._

val ts = mutable.TreeSet[Int](1, 2, 3, 8, 9)

println(ts.reverseIterator.mkString(", ")) // 9, 8, 3, 2, 1
```

Note: the above implementation is not thread safe.